# Using 32bit .lib library in a 64bit application

Tags: mfc, 32bit-64bit, libraries

I'm a starting programmer and I can't solve a problem I have now.

In MFC, I have a `.lib` binary file without the sources. I need to make a 64bit application that uses mentioned library file.

I thought about making 32bit console program and run one program from another, for example using IPC with `WM_COPY~` (or something like that), but the `.lib` file needs so many attributes like array, struct, pointer, ...

Is there an easier way to use that 32bit library in my 64bit application?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have any other alternative; you cannot load a 32-bit assembly in a 64-bit program, so you'll need to create a 32 bit application that your 64 bit application can talk to somehow.  There are lots of ways to do IPC, so find one that works for you.

Answer (score -3):

Uhmm strange, you simply can't put a big elephant into your home fridge but you still can insert in there a big chicken. If you can't do similarly with your 32 bit lib file, tell me why any of your 32bit applications can still work in 64 bit systems ? (:D) what sort of lib is that ?

Comment: What kind of answer is this?  You may want to look up WOW (Windows on Windows), which is a Windows subsystem that allows running 32-bit applications on 64-bit installations of Windows.